# java returning String [] from method

Tags: java, filereader

I have a filereader and need to use the text for the text of a loop of labels. I am having trouble.I need the text in the labels to be the aray of names from setLabel method.

main class a
    package build;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class a {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        a st = new a(); // object <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

            JButton button;
        JLabel headlabel;
        JLabel label[] = new JLabel[10];
        JRadioButton radioButton;
        JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4;


            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(panel1, c);
    panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(panel2, c);
    panel3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(panel3, c);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
            for (int e = 0; e < 8; e = e+1) {
                label[i]= new JLabel(st.setLabel()); // return String[] stocknames <<<<<<<<<<<
                label[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
                    c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
                    //c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);  //top padding
                    c.gridx = e;       //aligned with button 2
                    //c.gridwidth = 100;   //2 columns wide
                    c.gridy = i;       //third row
                    panel3.add(label[i], c);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
    * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
    * this method should be invoked from the
    * event-dispatching thread.
    */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stock Table");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Set up the content pane.
        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        createAndShowGUI();
                    }
            });
        }

    public String[] setLable() throws IOException {
        String file_name = "path";

        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
            String[] names = new String[aryLines.length];
            String[] links = new String[aryLines.length];

            int i;
            for(i=2; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
                int firstquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"")+1;
                int secondquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", firstquote+1);
                int thirdquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", secondquote+1)+1;
                int fourthquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", thirdquote+1);
                names[i] = aryLines[i].substring(firstquote, secondquote);
                links[i] = aryLines[i].substring(thirdquote, fourthquote);


            }

        return names;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }

    }

}
```

read file class

```
package build;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile {
    private String path;

    public ReadFile(String file_path) {
        path = file_path;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;

        for(i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;

    }

    int readLines() throws IOException {

        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

        String aLine;
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            numberOfLines++;
        }

        bf.close();

        return numberOfLines;

    }


}
```

*Completed*

```
package build;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class a {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        a st = new a();
        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

            JButton button;
        JLabel headlabel;
        JLabel label[] = new JLabel[10];
        JRadioButton radioButton;
        JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4;


            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            if (shouldFill) {
                //natural height, maximum width
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            }

        panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(panel1, c);
        panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(panel2, c);
        panel3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        pane.add(panel3, c);


        String[] labels = st.setLabel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
            for (int e = 0; e < 8; e = e+1) {
                label[i]= new JLabel(labels[i]);
                label[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
                    c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
                    //c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);  //top padding
                    c.gridx = e;       //aligned with button 2
                    //c.gridwidth = 100;   //2 columns wide
                    c.gridy = i;       //third row
                    panel3.add(label[i], c);
            }
        }




    }


    /**
    * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
    * this method should be invoked from the
    * event-dispatching thread.
    */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stock Table");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Set up the content pane.
        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public String[] setLabel() {
            String file_name = "path";
            String[] names = null;
            try {
                ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
                String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
                String[] links = new String[aryLines.length];
                names = new String[aryLines.length];

                int i;
                for(i=2; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
                        //System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
                        int firstquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"")+1;
                        int secondquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", firstquote+1);
                        int thirdquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", secondquote+1)+1;
                        int fourthquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", thirdquote+1);
                        names[i] = aryLines[i].substring(firstquote, secondquote);
                        links[i] = aryLines[i].substring(thirdquote, fourthquote);
                }
        }catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            return names;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {


         // get the values of x & y from class A
        int x = ReadWrite.getX();
        int y = ReadWrite.getY();
        // print them out
        //System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
            //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a very bad idea to have a set method to return something.  Consider refactoring objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of `String[] names` in `setLable()` before `try` block and similarly move the return statement after catch e.g.

```
    public String[] setLable() {
      String file_name = "path";
      String[] names = null;
      try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
        String[] links = new String[aryLines.length];
        names = new String[aryLines.length];

        int i;
        for(i=2; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            int firstquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"")+1;
            int secondquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", firstquote+1);
            int thirdquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", secondquote+1)+1;
            int fourthquote = aryLines[i].indexOf("\"", thirdquote+1);
            names[i] = aryLines[i].substring(firstquote, secondquote);
            links[i] = aryLines[i].substring(thirdquote, fourthquote);
        }
       }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
       }
       return names;
    }
```

**Please note:** If there is any exception before the population of `names`, then it will return`null`. Also I removed the `throws` as you are handling the exception(printing the message).

Lastly, method name doesn't sound appropriate. It should be better named as `getLables` or `getLableNames`.

You need to use the `String[]` of lables to set the the string as:

```
  String [] lables = st.setLabel();//change to getLables
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
    for (int e = 0; e < 8; e = e+1) {
      label[i]= new JLabel(lables[i]);//use string array index to set the string
```

Comment: i get java:135 error: cannot find symbol label[i] = new JLabel(st.setLabel()); symbol: method setLabel() location: variable st of type a

Comment: @user1516251 Updated the answer.  Also I removed the throws from the method (setLable) as you are handling the exception(printing the message).

Comment: @user1516251 If this is helpful, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking arrow sign down the vote count in front of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the question correctly, but I think you need to change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
    for (int e = 0; e < 8; e = e+1) {
        label[i]= new JLabel(st.setLabel()); // return String[] stocknames <<<<<<<<<<<
```

to this:

```
String[] labels = st.setLabel();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i+1) {
    for (int e = 0; e < 8; e = e+1) {
        label[i]= new JLabel(labels[i]);
```

Also note that you have the `public String[] setLable()` spelled wrong, it should be `public String[] setLabel()`.

Comment: i still get an error cannot find symbol st.setLabel() where do i place that at?

Comment: You do? After fixing the misspelling? Are you sure? Weird. What's the exact error message in full? Anyway, the fact that you even had misspellings in the code in the first place tells me that you are not using an IDE of any kind and you are just writing something and trying whether it compiles. Please install Eclipse or NetBeans and use that, they can warn you about typos right away and can often even suggest corrections for trivial mistakes.

Comment: The error i get is different now, ,java:133 erro: unreported exception IOException: must be caught or declared to be thrown String[] labels = st.setLabel(); 1error

Comment: Yes, that's because the `setLabel()` method has been declared as being able to throw an IOException and your `addComponentsToPane` method has not. You should either catch the exception or declare it to be thrown onwards.

Comment: I tried adding throws IOException to addComponentsToPane() what do i use?

Comment: That's declaring the exception to be thrown onwards, if that's what you are asking. How's it working now?

Comment: it gave me an unreported exception IOexception must be caught or declared to be thrown i just removed throws IOException from setLabel() and it works.